# json_decode() returns NULL - php

Tags: php, json

I have JSON code in a String variable `$response` which is

```
[{"StudentName":"ABC XYZ PQRS","RegNo":"13010xxx","EnrollNo":"","Photo":"","FatherName":"PQRS","MotherName":"MNOP","Branch":"Computer SciXXXXX","Sex":"M","Dob":"28-06-95","Height":"0.00","Weight":"0.00","IdentityMark":"","BloodGroup":" ","Degree":"B.Tech.","Semester":"VII","Section":"A","StudentMobile":"9999xxxxxx","FatherMobile":"96xxxxxxx","MotherMobile":"","FatherOffice":"","MotherOffice":"","EmailAddress":"sample@sample.sample","LAddress":"","LCity":"NGP","LDist":"NGP","LState":"MAHA","LPin":"44xxxx","LTelephone":"","LMobile":"","LEmail":"","PAddress":"","PCity":"NGP","PPin":"44xxxx","PDist":"NGP","PState":"MAHA","PTelephone":"-","PMobile":"","PEmail":"","GuardianName":"PQRS XYZ","Realation":"FATHER","GuardianAddress":"SAMPLE, \r\nMAHA","GuardianPhone":"96xxxxxxxx","Caste":"NULL","Category":"NULL"}]
```

and the value for `Photo` in above code is

```
"Photo":"HJKSFHKJHDJKHFDasdadQk0WMgAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAANwAAAEwAAAABABgAAAAAAOAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//Hj/+7m9uvt//bk//Dn/+vj//fz/+7k//Pr//Tu9MjL8tjXemeOiYO0r7TmwMT6ucv5w9D+0dL/ydL/ydD/xdD+xc39xdL/xM7/xc//xs/+u8z/x8v5v8v4wMv4wMf9xMn+ydH/wsj7tMX1wcX1urrruLjsl4rCmoCf3d7d7d/fzrO9zdDN0b2+3MO60ams2snC4NXV1MPPxa+858u418fD583GAAAA//Tr//bt//Hl//fm//////v3//Tt//Pp//fu/+7g5cvMvLLLb2eKqJbDtb7sxcrzxs79yNP/z9L/u9L/wNL+xs3/ydD/vs7/vND/yM//xcz/vcb/vsz8usb5tcPqw8Pzw8v5xM77x8z/wMr4yMP5t8LxtbnyoKjWdWaU0czX0tDR0rvF17a93tDR5NPP3sXA3ra3yK6z7NnSwbWq2dbC1svN7ubiAAAA///7//bp/fDm9t/V//rp///z/+7g/+3z/+jj/ODY793ienKIeG6Uq6vNu8Xzu8/4xND/x87+zND/wMr/ytD/xsr/wsr8xdL/xtD9ucr/ysn/xcv7vc37xMT2uMHut8Hvvcbxys3+y8j8u8j/xMz6vsLusbzrrLnjdHChxrW5v6/B6drZ3sbG2MHBy7Sy3NLR7tva8t/WyK6x4dXT4s3Jz7i20sncAAAA//////////ny/+nq/+vc//Hp//jv//fx//Lt7N7f8Obwbl+BhXipvbzhv8Pzysz8zc3+vsn/yc3/y8/+xNH/xcr/ytD+xND/us79w83/yc76usb8xcz2w8Xvvb/utMLsubnvuMr1xMz3x8z7wcX7tMHxurztqrXmgoWvyaaovaSr++nl2cnD49TF4tvV2cfC0r3F2dDI0bm1u7G45d/Y5cjA2sjYAAAA//////////////v4/+be//by/Orv//r5//Hu+Ofv6OHramB6kIexurzuwcrwwc36wc76w877ytH+xcv/ycn/zcv8u8z/w9H/xM37usb6wMT4tr/1ucP1vsHxsL7ws7vptbvkvcPvw8r1wMf6wcn7vcfwv7vsrrrllJ/OvZWhuaqy1MvG4MvBy7i0zbrAz8jJ9eLl2cTE5NXI1rS05dXl////////AAAA////////////////////////+/T29/T5//r2//r43tbXaVp2mY21vcHtx8f1v8n2xcj/zcr7xsz9xsT5wsP6t8n7xM/+xM//wcn5ur/+uMH6rb3xu8P3uMHtrr7vrbvnrLbhxL7qvcn6xcv5wcX7u8Xts73tprPhpKjSpo+g5dbfx62z5MzC9uPf7NTT8uPVyMnL2MDM9/D4////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////////nt/+rhyrvEZV5vmYyuu8DpvcL0wcr0xMn808b4uMv/wMP3wsP3vcr/yMj6vsv8zcv6ysv/u8z+xcDwwsPtssDvsrrps7bmsLbitbvmuMPtw8X2vsjzvMHxtLvou7PlpqvUj4erzMLK69Xa28LFyLis7NTKvrCy+ez0////////////////////////AAAA/////////////////////////////////////ubrxMLdbGd9j4Ceur3lvcLtv8bzsMj3wsXxu8z4vMT4u8Tytsf/vsv9xsz7xND/u87/wc3+usnysr7xsr3rsbvirbnlrLPisLbotMHswsPzusb3v8Lwt7vsqbDfqq7Yl4qtrKWiy8rH3dbY3dnW6NHE+fH+////////////////////////////AAAA/////////////////////////////////////v//8PP1mIicd2iDtb7juMDsvML3wsT0wMX0v8j2vMHzwMDyuMb3ycv9w9D+ytP/x87/ws/8xsf9v8L0sLfwtbbnsK/kqK/errPisL3zvMXzwcT0xsTsvb7so7PlqKrVeXWX5dfczb+8/uLo////////////////////////////////////////AAAA/////////////////////////////////////////+7mlY6sZ2F0tLrgucLqwMXzvcDzvcPzvsb1sbvww7vtvcP1ws38ys7/vc38rsLvtbvwuLzutb7rrLnrtbrko7LkrLDdrLHhsrzut8nyu8Hwu8HurrrprbjfnKvUko+2tbXF9OLi////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////////////////X/6+LreG2JuLHVtb3nrb7quMHzv8P3tbruu7nutL7swML4v8b3u8D3trnrpKjbnqXdnqHdo6bYqaripK/ipq/hqbXjq6/fqrXksL3yvsb0usHssrvosbbgravYvrXE28HB////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////4s/ZsLnRrK7LvLnkrL3nvMHyx8P1srnrrbnnt7/rt7/rs7zqqrDmqbLtpqrem6TWmJ7YoJvQlJ3TpKHTnqncp7HhrLHgo67btrjjuL/rw7/rr7zqsrjgqqjWm5uy////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////wbDKsq/Ztbvmub3svb3zt7/uprXouL/pv8L2xcj5u8j/wcn8v8v5uMDztL3ztr7wtLnnq7jrsb/utbjps7npr67jprDbsq7gtLjlu77nrrbosrblqa/c8d3t////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////////////////////////3/vrHSvrrpusLtuL3ttLntwr/qt8T4xM3/xc3/w9D/z9L/wc7/yc7/yM7/wM79zcf7v8r7tsf7wsD1xMTytbntrbXhq6/eqa/bt7bjtLTnqbnhrLDX//z/////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////0dz9r7vrw73twr/zxcP0x8n0xs781dT/zM3/0Nb/19v/xtX/293/0NL/zdP/yM7/ysv/v8v/wcv5v8XyxcHws7ftsrXjrbDkqa7iqbPerrfhrbHX//37////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////7eb/wcHzvsXzxMLvzMr3xs/+xs7/zdT/0tn/2dv/4Nr/zeD/0+H/0df/09v/zNn/0tX/xdL/t8z6vMj5s8Hzu7/vur/qubrlt7bipKzWsbXgrq7f//T0////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////3OX5vcLvy8r1x8j9xtD+1M7/wc7/wdD/3NH/2NX/2dn/zNr/3tn/zdr/0df/0Nj/2dj/zdX/vMn9y8r1vMX2vsPyscLyv8XrvLjvsLfjsrLdr6rY//Lu////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////wsb0vMj4187+1cr/zdL8yNf/wdb/1c3/2Mv9ys7/w9H+zMr/ytL/1M//xcv/z8/+ztL5ws38xsf6ucb0ur/xw8j5vL71uMT0wcDutL7wsLfosbXe+Ofq////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////zND4xsz70tP/09H/zdL/2dP/0dn/09L/z87/xMf7wL/+u8Lys7LuqrHoxLXsvrHnubzov7rvvcHxt8X3tcPxvsL0zcj6wcT2w8b3y8bxwr/nubrvv7nnsr3Z///5////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////6ez/zM75ytP/zNT/0NH/2tX/0dj/z9P/1c//ycn/0cv7v8b5xcb6yMP/ucX+ycX/z8P/x8f/xsb+wsT5tb/0tLryvbrzycj4xcb4wcX0yMbzwcHvwcLywcHst7rnxb7h////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////ydH5ztD/2dT/1NX/ytr/0t3/y9j/0tf/z8v+wcv8zs78w8b60MT/0sz/18D/1Mn/ysT/0sb/wr//1Mb5zMD1xsD0ur/wxcXyxcn308f5ycXxycDyu8DuvcLvt73stbvi8ebr////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////6uv/ycv3y8z/0tf/0tz/1dr/193/1Nf/y9f/zcr2xK/gzcfu0cDuzr3y0Lv1xbr3vbX307r8xcH7w8L4y8b5y8H1srnosrvsvsP3ysv0xsX1ycDyvMnvw8f0x8XyxsDxucDnwbvY////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////1tr7ys/70dP/0NX/0tn/2Nj/1t//z9r/ytT/1dT/xMf/vLv4trPqu67uyL33urn3x7/5zcb9xLf1tKftvq7kwrPms6vgu8HwwsX2ys33yMf0wcH3xcr4yMnvwsj1xMX4w8fzxb/m//n0////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////zdL+29H/zdT/0tj/1dv/0N7/2Nz/2t3/0dr/09T/3NP/ytf/zsv/xsj/xMP/x8v/ysj/xc3/zMv/wMT8xL73xb34xcP7vsr2yMj3vsT1ycj1xcr7zc33wcn9xc34w8n2wMrwxMHl4dTp////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////xM/41NH5y9L/ytP/0dv/zN7/19v/y97/093/1Nn/xNH/y9L/0s7/2dX/z9D/ysj8wsj8v8j7zs//0M38z8z6xsHzxMr4vsX1wcb20M/0x8j/xs77ycv4x8v0zc380sj2xMPyvbvuzL7c////////////////////////////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////z/////8ej/zdP4xM/3ys3/0NX/yt7/zN7/09//4+H/1OT/0Nz/zdb/1Nb/vcn9vsDwwcPzusDzycX6w8r4vcbzw8Lxx8Tyt8Lvw8L2xcv4vM75xs7/ysz/ytH/0NH/ycj8x8z91Mv1xMX0ycPxxbzi////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////+vn/5uL/0tz/zcr1zcz7ytD9zdX/z9T/z9z/2d3/yNz/4OL/4N//3dz/1Nr/zNj/xcTxwL/qv8H3wsv7ysf8xsr9wMb5t8HxwcT1zsf1ysX0ysv1v8z91tL/yNX/zdH/ztL/z8//08z5ys37yMTzv8Xwx73n/+/r6N3x49f6////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////7vL/3tb/2tr/xsb3yMv5x83/0Nb/09b/zt7/1Nv/zNr/19v/3d3/3OD/4tz/1dj/xsj3xMX5xs3/0Mv8ucP5xsj4ycz9v731ysP7wsn50Mr8zNP/ztT/ydD/zs/+yNP91c7208LiyZ+5y7nfzcruvcXvu7/nsrjlvcj6wsHs6dXs////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////5Nr/x83/ys3/ycn2z8z+x8//z9j/09f/1uD/2eL/2uH/3+L/2eP/39//z97/xcv/srLvtKndw8P1zNH/yc39u7/0t7TnsrnlyMX0vsX4yND8ztL/zdD/ydD/y9D/ztP/0NH/0M/+x7njx4STyMj0vMDxuL7ov8HmuL/tubLlzLzd////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////7Ov/z9j/2d//0tT/xc/6ztP90dn/297/1N7/2OL/3eL/19//3N//3N3/3dn/19v/3tz/zsz/usP/19P/3N7/0tf/wsv9qaXrubryzM3/yc37y9L/x9L/z9X/ztX/1Nn/19b/0dX/ytb/0dH/0Mz7z873wcPyv7zksrHcu73lubfnuLXm//z6////////////////////AAAA////////////////////2tj/3N7/0cz/xsf5y8r21tn+0tf/1d7/2d7/3uT/3uj/2+P/1+L/4t//0tv/0tj/6d3/3t//0dr/3OX/4Oj/29//x9n/ydX/z87+0Mv/vs7+ys//yNP/z9f/ydf/ydb/29n/0tr/1tL/ytH/zsv/w8v5t8Dxt7zntrTavbzny8PuuLXp1Mrv////////////////////AAAA//////////////////T/1dL/0cr/1cP/y8//yNH70db/09z/1OP/5OD/3+f/3Of/3+X/0uL/5uP/1N7/1tv/2Nb/3tz/2+L/5un/6e3/5eX/4eT/0dT/yMr+x8r9xs/4xtD/0tX/2tX/z9X/2Nn/z9z/3dv/19j/ydT/zND/0cn7zMf1uLrmtLXjsLXrtLTox77yurnm//n/////////////////AAAA////////////////1dj/09T/vL3/xMb4yNT/1tH/1tf/0dr/5d//1uH/4OL/3uT/3t//397/4eH/3eD/3t3/09n/4Nr/2eP/5+f/5PT/6On/1t7/0dv/zMb5x8X3zMz0z8//19f/0tn/1df/1tn/0tv/zNz/zNn/y9j/xdP92M78vsP0u7zjxrzlysrytLTut7fusLHo1M3v////////////////AAAA////////////8/f/ysn7zM7/xMj9vLz1zsj6y8//ztj/2tr/1eD/1+L/4d7/29z/1dz/2t3/0d7/4OD/097/ztf/3t3/3+H/5un/9+7/3+L/1dr/xNH/w8j5xcf3yNH+2NX/0Nf/ytX/09X/y9X/1Nb/1Nb/19f/0tT/y9D/yc/+wMb0t77pwbnqv8PyvbHsrrbwsrbss7Ps//v8////////////AAAA////////////zNP/uMP+x8n8wcj/r7H6x8j4ydD90tb/2dv/2d//2tz/0tv/ztr/2t7/0tn/0tr/1dn/3Nz/0Nv/ydf/1Nz/6+n/4uf/3t3/z9f/ysr/zMv1x8f+29f/0dP/xtH/0db/xdb/ztX/wtT/y9X/zNT/yM//y8j7wsz5wMLwv73qvLvntLvntbDpusH3t7Xsra/o3Mjy////////////AAAA////////////wcb/vcL8v8v6wMf+qbT1u7zoys76ztX/09X/1tr/zNr/1dv/09f/1NT/zdD/zND/0sz/zMr/0NT/zdf/1tj/6ej/7Or/4t//y9f/vcX4wMf7vMz7xtD8z83/wdH/xdH/ytX/zNf/y9j/z9b/vc//xc37xsj3v8zyvb7ru7zpr7PZnZ/XtbXqwMD0trjtuLbqtrPv////////////AAAA////////////usD0t7j8x8P5xsv/vsT0ranMzMv3vdD8zNf/0NP/x9T/y9P/y8z/xs38ycj9wcj/zMv/xcj9y8v9v83/1Nb/2uH/7uf/1+D/ztT/wc33vsbyxsP2xcr5xs38xc78vMz5x8r8v8j8xs38wsz+w87/ucTxwMXvw8Dts77strvljoq0mZvVs7ntvsb1t7TtrrLtoJzr/+//////////AAAA/////////v7/tLXvurv0xsn/wsj6wMf3lpGtysn4ydL9yc//zcr+ycn8s8H0yMjxx833vsL0uMPzxMP4u7/zxcj0vcj809H/5eT/5ef/4eL/y9H/wcTyvMLywcDzxsj5vsb3vMP0wL/2vMH2uMDzwMPwu8Hwvr/uuMfywMDxrr3wsr3oqbPejIKfrrrkx8Tvusf0r7burq/qmprl28vx////////AAAA////////6+7/sa3suLr0vMT5zMb4vMjyloSZxsL0vc78w9T/wsj6v8DyyMHz3NXz0rjNpImbzcLQyMnvwL7vucDyuMb2xcb/097/3uX/1t3/v8r/vML1usHwvr/ttr/0vsTuwMbsvbzjwcPiur/mrrfmsLXltbjgtrzstbvtrbnlsLbkqajPkIultL3puL7uwsH1trnrsaztlpXk4Mbv////////AAAA////////+/3/tLPoxcf60Mj5z87vrrjkjHuYvMTrydD6xsv5rr7toarb08nl4tPphW6SdmJ+iHOPz93szsXyr7Tsv8r3uMX8ytT/1t3/09b/wc74vb/xucHwsrfp0Mbt2tr5wbDNe2yMfWeDzsPMt7vbp6zWparer7jpr7vorrLrsbPehYq4joqfvb/pu7fsuLnrsLPxqKTokIPV8N34////////AAAA//////////////z//vn////////9i4mZjoOYwMHzw875vsbyvL3spqbanJbKuaq8j2mLbmFxeWqJs63No6rbt7nts7/zu7/4v83629n/x9T/w8X1vb/vt7/wvLjqsLDb0czmtY6smnCGjXmXrImSsau5kZC8n6LWsbbqsrvrrLfkrbHdgn2fiHSFpavPoabYrK7lrrHklIzUq6Tg////////////AAAA////////////////////////1MnPgHB6kouku8Lwucvxusb4vsTzt8DytL3vub/kp6zgnKbRqq3XpKjeurjpt7zuvcHzv7/uws77zNX/yNL9yMnwtr/yuLjtt7vurLXlua7gi4nEb2eUZmGQdnKeipTAjJrKmanarbPitrfnrrbhqq7aenmaZV1ybF5v//j3//T/z8jxxb3o/PD/////////////AAAA////////////////////////iYafcGV6n5y0r8HuxsHrssDrwsbzusHyx8TxxcfzxMjtucXwt77nsrzvvrrrsb3ws8LtycPwwM/3yNP+wMv7vsjxvcXwtbvvvLzpsLjqrrjptbrpsLnis7nlr7DenqzaqK3dpbLjrbTirrfhrbLip67YdnKeYFRsYltt//Hb////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////9ePedWV8cGN2oaK9usDqtcHktLXfpq/atrrct7znu7TfnKfKmJGuk46unp27pKXCs7TevLrhwsXwwszzzc/8ys33xcntv8HvurzsurrnsLnjprHetbfnuL3nq7zsrrvlsrTlqbXkubjkrrHhq7Pir7Liq63Vcm6YX1hnZ1to6d3Q////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////m5mmZGFvaF16m6bOs8Hrub3tu8DrrKvSp67YrrPXqJ/Nj4yxhICkjYCmhH6nkZO9tbjgysXzzdP/yNb/zdT/0NH+ys30tLTjs7bhsbjhmJjFh32cmI6mkYaipae9rKvVsq/YrbHdobLZn6TPqLDWtbTdoq3bd3CYY1VjZVtltZZ8////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////jIOTY1tta2B2qqzRtLnptsHtvsbwycrzvLvmvLjYubjfvbzdxcjq09Lz2tL9193/09r/29//2dv/z9z/yNb/4dr/xdj7wcjtwcjqx8Dpm5vBhH2he26XgneOg3WQhX2hnJ+7npfDgoWtj46yrq7ZpLHeoq/ZcWmTX1djZllidWly////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////fHSJYlhtZGF2qKvQr7vsucHtvcf0vcn8wtD4x8v4y9T70tr/2Nz/29v/2d//1+P/1N3/1dn/0tn/zNj/zNX/1dv/z93/zNX/y875x8/5yMTxtMfnur3lrLDWqp/CmZbBjomtjIyzlZ7FoqPUoq3XqrXYoKzTYV2AW1ReXlVhcGRv///6////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////cmh/X1hraF11nZ/MsL3otsPvuMX3xsf0xcz8wdH/zNL/0tv/0Nb/093/0tv/3Nr/ztn/xtn/yNf/xtX/x9f/vNr/x9T9y9T/ydb/u878yc37w87zu8f1wMbzsMHrtbPgm6TRnqzapKnYqKnUra7Sp63bkpvFX1duWlBeYVBfZlxm/+3X////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////bmZ1X1dlYFlriImppa/grb7stsXwucn5u8z8vtL/vtT/xtP/zNf/ydv/zdj/z9n/y9L/ys//w9D/yNP/wNX/y9T/wdD9xdL7w8//x8z7w8z7vsn2wsL2vcLztL7srLfirLfiqa/coq3ZoqnTn6vYo6rTe3WZVVBmXFFcXFVcYllg1rqu////////////////////////AAAA////////////////7+LqXltnWFViWFJpaWaCoJ3DsLjhuMDxvMz5vs/6w9D6yND/zNT/xtf/x9L/xc7/ws//vdD/xNL/u9D+ys/+xc//w9D9wdH+xsn9xMX8uMX4ucf4tsX0uMD2uMLzu8DurbrurLjgq7PiobDfmqnVkJ/JfIKkXlp2WVFgVVFaYVRaW1hfhHN0////////////////////////AAAA////////////////oJKbYFhoZVxpV1BlXFNvg4KlqrDks8DswMH3vc78u878vsv8x8z9usn3vs7/xM38x8r/xND9vcz/uc3/xs//xtD+ycz8xM/6tc75tMr7wsb4ssb5scXzscLztr7wtb3vu7ropbrmobPlpK7kmKHNcXulXlp4VlBiVU9ZV05cWlJZYlxidWZv///8////////////////////AAAA////////////////e3aHYltnZmRxVVBmXFNsenqQqKnZsL7ovcL1u8r3vs/5wMr5xcz3tcn9w8z/yc/9xM7/wc/7vsn2wcf/ws38vM37wc37wMj9vcn8vcn2r8b9uMX3ucXyuMPxtb/sscPvqL/zsL3opLHhlqPSf4CkZl19WVFpVU5aVlBfV09YWVRaWFZhcWFv///9////////////////////AAAA////////////////dW+JcGNzW1BjU1hhXVJibGFxmp7FpbXotL7utMPxt8XzvMjzvM31xsz2ws76vs36wcr/v87/y83+wcn8vdD9u8v/wc76vc37vcT6t8v5tsj0usf1t8T0scL2scHvrr7ssrzorLXinanVe4SuYll+WkxnVktgVlFXVk1ZVlBZXVJaX1ZhbmFx////////////////////////AAAA////////////////eHB9ZV1mVU5eUE9gUUxfVFNpgH6Xo6fQpbPgqrnqurzpqsPnv8j0v8nyus71uMn2wMj5xc/8vs39t8n6tM32t8j1t8j6usnzs8n4uMr3wcT5uMT2sr3vtL/uqLrqqL7rsbnjpa7ak57JfHyVWVR3VE5nWEhhUkxXUkxYXVFYWk5jX1hddmRt////////////////////////AAAA////////////////eHB/XlttVFFfWkxhXVBeVEphWlFjaWd9e3+hk57Cpa3VpLLboazZnqvXpa3YnqbftLbps77sr7fwsr/1r8Xxtr/1s8PyrMPysMT1tcXxsL3prb7vtL3nsL/qrbzko7PhoK3bmqPLeH+pbGWEX1pyXFNlVlFaUkhaWE5YWk5bXE1bXlhcb2Fr///2////////////////////AAAA////////////////e22CWlVlU01bTEhZUUxcSEdaUktZYFNoV1hoYlp2a2WCeG+LgoOjho+3jZzDkp7Hj5jGmKHUpa3aprDfpbzlqrbpqbjpprvno7vonLPlo7XfprDfn7DeqLLcprDelKnUlp/JiI60bmiNcmV7ZFpzWFBjWVBfWU9dVk5dXFZhW01cY1ZebF5v///7////////////////////AAAA////////////////f3SFYlppWU9bUktZUUlgUEhXUklbVElgVU1jVUxgW1FfW1RlX1duaF14cWeOcm+SdnCabnCYhIyui5jLlaDPl6bUlKXTkaPUlaDRjJzFh5TGh5DBiJK9jYq2gYeqgYmueH2laViGYVp2XlttWVFlW09fZ1loYltkWVFfWFFfYVFeYFRoc2Zw///8////////////////////AAAA////////////////lIukZ2JxXFRgUk1aUUdYU0hZVUZdUkhWUklZUklYVkteXVRiaVp1ZllvcWB5c2V8bWJ/ZV53YF17dmyPa2qRb3OYcXKgcXebdXCYb26ZcXKda3OeYWeUY2KEWU9xX1duXVh5VU5qTUlZTkdfTUlZZFJlZFRlWVJiYFJiXVFfYlRgZV5pi4aG//Xs////////////////////AAAA////////////////3tffbGdtY1hjY1hlUU5YVktaTkhWU0dZVkxaWkxbYltjX1dlZlhgdV1pd11sY1lqalhtZ1VoYFRuVVBsW1NrWFJuWFBuU1RyalV1VUtuVU9tXFRvWU5xV0dpVVBpUUNeUkdhT0xdUEddTUhZUExcVkxcU01ZVE5aXVBfYlRjcGJuZlxmd2l0//32////////////////////AAAA////////////////////gnqIZ15pYFVlZltfUU9dVVFZV0lZW1BeYFZhY1lmaltkXVFfXlBdYFZkaFhmXFRlVUdcT0NgUkldWVBiXE5jVUpgVEdoXFFiUD1bTkZZVkxZVkxgV0pgV0xgTkRWT0RYT0NaTUdRSURSU0RVTUdRTUlTXlxcX1djXllhZVtma2FphW98////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////2tHibWVwYltoYlhnXFFfXk5eWkxeVU9dVElVTkhVVEpYXVFebFthfGBqc2FnaFZqal1pYFRoWk1lYVBfYkxeVUhcV0diW0tVS0lUTUlYVElbWEpZXk1cTkhWTUNUTkRaTUhYSURWSElVSUZPTz5OUklSVENeVlFXXVFbY1hiaF5mpZWY////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////eXR+amBsbF5maVtjVVBXYFNgXk5cX1Rhb15iZVRhYVBedVtldl5ocl5pd2Zvb15oXVNeXVJbXVFeWkxYV0dXTUhhW0dOUkdZXFRhWk9eW01eVEdZTkVRUktYVUdYV0xaUkhZTEhRTj9OT0hQTUlWTUlVV1lbXkxgb1tfbWNw8NDR////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////hoSVd2l0aVtqYFRialdjW1BfVk1UXkxfZ1lgcF5od2BtelxlZ1JhaFRfZFNiWVJmZ1RkUkhdT0RWU0dZTUNSTUhaZFJaXVBgZ1RhT0RWTUNSTkZVTUNSQ0ZSTEVQTkRRVU9XcXV8TkZOTUhRUkpWT1FWXVJiZV5pZ15pcGZ1///9////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////9u/wfXV+bmFwX1ZkYFRhXVVaZFRhVFRha15ic2Fke11qbFtpZFRndGNqg2twdmRybVdlaldlYkxgUklgWVFbW1RjYVJaVFFZV0dZTU1UVEhWTUhVUklVU0lVTkZTS0ZQT0dQUEJNTkRRVkNWUUtcWk1aYVVgaVxma15uuqWs////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////taq6c253XltnZFtkW1hoWVVaZVRga1ljYVBgb1pidV5meWNwjnR2j3F4dGBqZlNkV0hdWE1YW09XVUxZVU5hXk1VUkRWTERWSURMS0ZSTkdVTkRLT0JWSkNQSE1UUkdQT0dUTUlPYFVeXVFeXkxiX1locWFtfXJ8//Ds////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////oZakdGlyYltmbl5pZlhmclpme2Nqf2hxZlhqY1lkdWVteWN6bmJtb1prZVRoUkldUktbWUtYWUtYVk1iZFJZU0pYTkdVVVFdU0VSS0RMR0RMSj9OS0RNW0lYTURWUkpTWk1ZWVVdY1djaF5pc2Rve2174MrL////////////////////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////////z4f32FamNuYltoW1FfXFVoZ1Zeb1xkcFppfWlxhGttc2NwZ1hkaVBlWVJfclpmdV1lZVdnWkpcVVBiXk5TVkxYVkhYUEhUW0ZUVEhaTUhVUEdUU0NVUURTUUtVWkxVXFRbY1xjbGZvgHN0gH+C7+vp////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////5Nvpf3t/aVpvY1dnXFViZ1tjaF5mclxob1tnaFRhclxod2JoalpgVk1bXlBeYVRdUUdRZFNoUU1iaFRcVk5fWE5bUlFXVkxjUkxbVktXV0lXUEdZUkdUUU1ZWVFYXVhidXCDmJefzsTW//z/////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////4d3rgHiIcGZzY1pqYltlaFNoaFRlZ2FoeGRyhWVxgWlzeWBwbF5qZlpqY1dqZ1tjXVBfUkhiX05bWVBfTExUVU9fU01aUE1cVkpYVUtnUUlWUU1abGdtW1hjcGZ18drb////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////7Ov3eXWBcmlyZVdpaV1reWtujnRzkXJ2g211dmNtZ1dmXVJWWU9cXVBfY1ZgY1hgVUxjY1NaVkxZVE1gWk5ZVk1UUE1ZTUlRVUlWU05XWFBbXFVhY2FprKCf////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////iYWfc254a2Fxa15piW91hWt1dmZvfWhufWd3dWZye2Zpd15lYFVeU0tZVFFjZ1dgWFRgYFRlU1BcVUtZU0dhTUtUVk1TV0hXWFVedGx0mZOS/e3p////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////4tjmk4Gafm54fXJ9dWZvfmtvfGtwfWZvk3p5e2l8bVdjVFNebVdiYFZoalVgXVFgUU1UYk5cW0hZUU1aWU5bVVFcXVJgaF9uppqi//b6////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////xL3Sn5KdlISMnn+JiHJ3eGhvempxeGhycF1seGZyZ1dpY1pwcWFnZltnZFRlXFRoVU9fWU9hW1JiXFZkbmlvkoWM/PD2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////7+jz1s3bkpKmm46Sno2ZfXl/d2l0gG16cWRvaV50e2VpaVhoY1dpX1dkVFViX1hoYlpqbGZwmIyY////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////X3v7e6loORfXN6eXSDgG5wamRxZmdzYmdwfXN6gHaJi4ODyb/E////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAA///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////6//////////f88/Dw//r/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AAAALLLLLL"
```

When I run `var_dump(json_decode($response));`, it outputs `NULL`.
I tried solutions given on similar questions here at `stackoverflow.com` but none of them worked.

Edit : 
Code

```
$wsdl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ANDROID/AndroidService.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl );
$action = "http://tempuri.org/GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION";
$location = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ANDROID/AndroidService.asmx";
$response = $client->__doRequest ( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <REGNO>13010602</REGNO>
</GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',$location, $action, SOAP_1_1 );
$json = json_decode ( $response );
var_dump ( $json );
```

Comment: Look at your response, actually Photo is coming as empty

Comment: Where did you encode you JSON part .

Comment: I put this response in a variable and it is working fine.

Comment: Photo is not coming as empty. I have posted the value for photo in second code box so that it'll easier to debug.

Comment: @urfusion I did the same. It works. But does not work when $response  variable is used.

Comment: show your full code.

Comment: your response `json` is not valid `json`. check your response on `http://jsonlint.com/`

Comment: 'jsonlint.com' is displaying that it is a valid json.

Comment: As a side note; dont use real values like IP, hostnames, domains for security purposes.

Comment: yep. 
 
response is empty because of invalid syntax of json. check with json_last_error(). when getting response by api

Comment: @JayRathod i had checked your response. Your response contains xml data other than json. So this gives null on json_decode. You need to take json data from that xml response first

Comment: @JayRathod check out this response. Its working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960611/json-decode-returns-null-php/34961154#34961154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works fine**

```
$wsdl = "http://2xx.xx7.2xx.xxx/YCCEANDROIDANDROID/AndroidService.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl );
$action = "http://tempuri.org/GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION";
$location = "http://2xx.xx7.2xx.xxx/YCCEANDROIDANDROID/AndroidService.asmx";
$response = $client->__doRequest ( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <REGNO>13010602</REGNO>
</GET_STUDENT_INFORMATION></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',$location, $action, SOAP_1_1 );

$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $response);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);

$xml_resp = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);

$xml_resp = json_decode($xml_resp["Body"]["GET_STUDENT_INFORMATIONResponse"]["GET_STUDENT_INFORMATIONResult"], true);

print_r($xml_resp);
```

**Problem with your code**

Soap response was an xml data. We need to parse xml first and later json_decode the required response

Comment: response is empty because of invalid syntax of json. check with `json_last_error()`. when getting response by api

Comment: run the code provided by the user not only the response.

Comment: @urfusion tried user code includeing soap part. Its giving an error ==> PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://2xx.xx7.2xx.xxx/ANDROID/AndroidService.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://2xx.xx7.2xx.xxx/ANDROID/AndroidService.asmx?WSDL"

Comment: it is because the user remove some information for security reason.

Comment: He removed ip address. SO i cant test that part of the code

Comment: @urfusion tanx for showing code. I had checked it. response is an xml data. So its giving error

Comment: Thank you very much Ijas Ahamed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ur coding and it seems to work fine

```
<?php

 $response = ["StudentName"=>"ABC XYZ PQRS","RegNo"=>"13010xxx","EnrollNo"=>"","Photo"=>"*Your long code*","FatherName"=>"PQRS","MotherName"=>"MNOP","Branch"=>"Computer SciXXXXX","Sex"=>"M","Dob"=>"28-06-95","Height"=>"0.00","Weight"=>"0.00","IdentityMark"=>"","BloodGroup"=>" ","Degree"=>"B.Tech.","Semester"=>"VII","Section"=>"A","StudentMobile"=>"9999xxxxxx","FatherMobile"=>"96xxxxxxx","MotherMobile"=>"","FatherOffice"=>"","MotherOffice"=>"","EmailAddress"=>"sample@sample.sample","LAddress"=>"","LCity"=>"NGP","LDist"=>"NGP","LState"=>"MAHA","LPin"=>"44xxxx","LTelephone"=>"","LMobile"=>"","LEmail"=>"","PAddress"=>"","PCity"=>"NGP","PPin"=>"44xxxx","PDist"=>"NGP","PState"=>"MAHA","PTelephone"=>"-","PMobile"=>"","PEmail"=>"","GuardianName"=>"PQRS XYZ","Realation"=>"FATHER","GuardianAddress"=>"SAMPLE, \r\nMAHA","GuardianPhone"=>"96xxxxxxxx","Caste"=>"NULL","Category"=>"NULL"];

 $h = json_encode($response);
 $var = json_decode($h);
 print_r($var);

?>
```

I got this as output :

```
stdClass Object ( [StudentName] => ABC XYZ PQRS [RegNo] => 13010xxx [EnrollNo] => [Photo] => 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 [FatherName] => PQRS [MotherName] => MNOP [Branch] => Computer SciXXXXX [Sex] => M [Dob] => 28-06-95 [Height] => 0.00 [Weight] => 0.00 [IdentityMark] => [BloodGroup] => [Degree] => B.Tech. [Semester] => VII [Section] => A [StudentMobile] => 9999xxxxxx [FatherMobile] => 96xxxxxxx [MotherMobile] => [FatherOffice] => [MotherOffice] => [EmailAddress] => sample@sample.sample [LAddress] => [LCity] => NGP [LDist] => NGP [LState] => MAHA [LPin] => 44xxxx [LTelephone] => [LMobile] => [LEmail] => [PAddress] => [PCity] => NGP [PPin] => 44xxxx [PDist] => NGP [PState] => MAHA [PTelephone] => - [PMobile] => [PEmail] => [GuardianName] => PQRS XYZ [Realation] => FATHER [GuardianAddress] => SAMPLE, MAHA [GuardianPhone] => 96xxxxxxxx [Caste] => NULL [Category] => NULL )
```

Comment: I have posted the full code, hope it will help you understand my issue.

Comment: Sorry but, in my case, $response has different value than what you have have assigned in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Photo contains some characters the json_decode can not work with.
I had a similar issue while parsing out the crawled content of the page.

I have a solution; (if you are willing to sacrifice the integrity the data value of the Photo :( )

Removing those unicode characters like this will make json_decode work:

```
$response=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $response);

$json = json_decode ( $response );
```